# Cannot update List1: it has no PK

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2012, sqlite-net

I'm trying to update a record in a database, the changes are made on the list that I create for the page, but when I try to update the database itself, I get an error that states

> Cannot update List1: it has no PK

The application breaks on the last line of code. My table has a primary key. It should be `Tno` in `Students`.

```
private void ChangeMajor_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var query = Roster_Students.Where(s => s.Tno == Tno_TextBox.Text);
    foreach (var student in query)
        student.Major = ChangeMajor_TextBox.Text;

    App.DBConnection.Update(this.Roster_Students);        
}
```

Comment: Just double check the PK is in place...

Comment: Do you have the DDL for the table?

Comment: Tno_TextBox.Text returns a string. Did you tried casting it to an int in your Where clause?

Comment: @AzharKhorasany
Tno is actually a string in my table.

Comment: @JohnLBevan Here is the DDL:
0|Tno|varchar(10)|0|1
1|Name|varchar(50)|0|0
2|Major|varchar(10)|0|0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying the code a little seemed to resolve the issue. Here is the new code:

```
private void ChangeMajor_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var query = Roster_Students.Where(s => s.Tno == Tno_TextBox.Text);
    foreach (var student in query) {
        student.Major = ChangeMajor_TextBox.Text;
        App.DBConnection.Update(student);
    }
}
```